# Reports using microsoft viewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

How to create parametrized reports using microsoft report viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Put more details in your question, but as i understand the [MSDN ReportViewer Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(VS.80).aspx) will be very nice to you learn more by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXJmRHgSAS8&feature=related

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I would avoid the Microsoft report viewer control. Just use a browser control, and browse to the report, passing in the parameters in the URL like you would when using a browser.

This is much better for many reasons.

1. The MS Report Viewer Control has a lot of bugs that you will be stuck with.
2. The browser and the report viewer render the reports differently (slightly) such as with margins etc. So you will have to tweak most of your reports if you ever switch to a web application and need to use the browser to access reports. This brings me to the next issue . . .
3. If you ever need to go to a web application, you will need to reimplement how you call reports, pass parameters, etc. instead of just using the browser functionality you already have created (you access the reports differently using the control vs. using a browser)

Otherwise, if you truly want to use the Report Viewer control, here is a sample (using .NET 2.0):

```
    ReportViewer rvReportViewerControl = new ReportViewer();
   rvReportViewerControl.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
    rvReportViewerControl.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://<SERVERNAME>/ReportServer");
    rvReportViewerControl.ServerReport.ReportPath = "<FOLDER PATH TO REPORTS>");
    rvReportViewerControl.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameterInfoCollection rpInfoCollection = rvReportViewerControl.ServerReport.GetParameters();
    if (rpInfoCollection.Count > 0)
    {
         List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();

         foreach (ReportParameterInfo reportParameter in rpInfoCollection)
         {
              string parameterName = reportParameter.Name.ToString();
              string parameterValue = "";
              bool isParameterVisible = reportParameter.Visible;
              paramList.Add(new ReportParameter(parameterName, parameterValue, isParameterVisible));
         }

         rvReportViewerControl.ServerReport.SetParameters(paramList);
    }

    rvReportViewerControl.RefreshReport();
```

[This site](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) has a lot of useful information.

Comment: Did some editing, my first code wouldn't have been quite right. It should be good to go now though.